# Remove all ENTER_FRAME listeners

Tags: actionscript-3, listeners

Is there a way to remove ALL ENTER_FRAME event listeners at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if you've been keeping careful track of your listeners.  There is no "removeAll" type functionality for event listeners, so it helps to collect your listeners in an easy-to-manage place.

Comment: This.  In fact, not only is there no "remove all" functionality for event listeners, there is no way to do any kind of inspection beyond "do you respond to ENTER_FRAME?", so you couldn't even do an exhaustive recursive check and remove ones that you find, because you have no way of reading the target of the events.  Your best bet is to be careful about how you add them.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to create a class that handles adding event listeners to `IEventDispatcher` objects, registering those objects and removing all events listeners at the same time. The following is a example I quickly made to demonstrate this:

EventListeners.as:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    public class EventListeners
    {
        private var _objectDictionaries:Vector.<Dictionary>;

        public function EventListeners()
        {
            init();

        }// end function

        public function addEventListener(object:IEventDispatcher,
                                         type:String,  
                                         listener:Function, 
                                         useCapture:Boolean = false,
                                         priority:int = 0,
                                         useWeakReference:Boolean = false)
        {
            object.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);

            var objectDictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
            objectDictionary["object"] = object;
            objectDictionary["type"] = type;
            objectDictionary["listener"] = listener;
            objectDictionary["useCapture"] = useCapture;
            _objectDictionaries.push(objectDictionary);

        }// end function

        public function removeAll():void
        {
            for each(var objectDictionary:Dictionary in _objectDictionaries)
            {
                var object:IEventDispatcher = objectDictionary["object"] as IEventDispatcher;
                var type:String = objectDictionary["type"] as String;
                var listener:Function = objectDictionary["listener"] as Function;
                var useCapture:Boolean = objectDictionary["useCapture"] as Boolean;

                object.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);

            }// end for

            init();

        }// end function

        private function init():void
        {
            _objectDictionaries = new Vector.<Dictionary>();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Main.as:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var _eventListeners:EventListeners;
        private var _sprite1:Sprite;
        private var _sprite2:Sprite;

        public function Main()
        {
            init();

        }// end function

        public function init():void
        {
            _eventListeners = new EventListeners();
            _sprite1 = new Sprite();
            _sprite2 = new Sprite();

            _eventListeners.addEventListener(_sprite1, Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
            _eventListeners.addEventListener(_sprite2,  Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

            trace("_sprite1.hasEventListener = " + _sprite1.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME));
            trace("_sprite2.hasEventListener = " + _sprite2.hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE));

            _eventListeners.removeAll();

            trace("\n_eventListeners.removeAll() invoked\n");

            trace("_sprite1.hasEventListener = " + _sprite1.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME));
            trace("_sprite2.hasEventListener = " + _sprite2.hasEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE));

        }// end function

        private function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {};
        private function addedToStageHandler(e:Event):void {};

    }// end class

}// end package
```

The output from running this example is the following:

```
_sprite1.hasEventListener = true
_sprite2.hasEventListener = true

_eventListeners.removeAll() invoked

_sprite1.hasEventListener = false
_sprite2.hasEventListener = false
```

Comment: +1... The only drawback is the addEventListener syntax, that differs from the natural form (you need to pass the EventDispatcher object first)...

Comment: @NemoStein think of this `addEventListener()` as `registerEventDispatcher()` instead, and you'll realize that parsing the `IEventDispatcher` object is not a drawback but rather the point of the method. But from first glance I can understand why this `addEventListener()` method appears like a malformed version of it's synonymous counterpart `IEventDispatcher.addEventListener`. I just gave it the same name because the methods are similar but not exactly the same.